# GWT Create JAVAscriptObject form string

Tags: gwt, httpresponse

I have a model such as bellow.

```
public class ColumnDtoWrapper extends JavaScriptObject{

protected ColumnDtoWrapper() {}

public final native JsArray<ColumnDto> getfields() /*-{
    return this.fields;
}-*/;

public final native void gettable() /*-{
return this.table;
}-*/;

public final native JavaScriptObject getHasMany() /*-{
    return this.hasmany;
}-*/;
}
```

I Make server call like

```
RequestBuilder build = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL);
    try {
        Request request = build.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if(200== response.getStatusCode()){

                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Window.alert("error : " + exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Window.alert("try err");
    }
```

When i got success responce in JSON string.
I want to convert that string as ColumnsDtoWrapper.

somthing like ColumnDtoWrapper col = new ColumnDtoWrapper(responce.getText());

but it not works is there any good way to convert string to JavaScriptObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JsonUtils.safeEval`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html#safeEval%28java.lang.String%29):

```
ColumnDtoWrapper col = JsonUtils.safeEval(response.getText());
```

Comment: i uses following way.`public static final native <T extends ColumnDtoWrapper> T getResponse(String responseString) /*-{
     return eval('(' + responseString + ')');
 }-*/;`